# php and mysql database need info in a row

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have been working on a rank page which will show some data from my MySQL database. It's showing the data fine but I can't figure out how I can make it so people get ranked 1-2-3 and so on. I don't think I can use the ID from my database as it's static at a number. Here is the code i'm currently working on:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Store Topliste</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Denne side viser dig en liste over dem der har flest Credits i Store</h4></br></br>
<table>
    <tr>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Navn</th>
                <th>Credits</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("IP", "USER", "PASS", "DATABASE");
    if ($conn-> connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT name, credits from store_players ORDER BY credits DESC";
    $result = $conn-> query($sql);

    if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>". '0' ."</td><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>". $row["credits"] ."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else {
        echo "0 result";
    }

    $conn-> close();
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The place where i currently have '0' is where i would like to have some kind of thing that counts from 1-2-3 in the first row "Rank"

Here is a picture of how it looks now:

[image: Website]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add some data and table structure and add you mysql version

Comment: It's better to keep PHP and HTML code separate. Don't mix it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable that you increment for each row.

```
    if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
        $rank = 1;
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>". $rank ."</td><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>". $row["credits"] ."</td></tr>";
            $rank++;
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
```